# byebug, next into application code only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

When I press `n` (or type `next`) in a Rails app, very often I get into a gem's methods that I'm not interested in, and I have to press `n` lots of times just to continue execution.

Is there a way, beside filling my code with `byebug` calls, to just stay in my app's frames?
Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `c n` to continue to a particular line `n`. Byebug will run at full-speed, then stop at the line you gave it. That means that gems or not, they won't be noticed by you as they'll be processed at high-speed.

The built-in help says:

```
(byebug) help continue
c[ont[inue]][ nnn]

Run until program ends, hits a breakpoint or reaches line nun
```

Comment: The Tin Man's suggestion is a good one as a workaround, but `next` command stepping inside gem methods __is a bug__.

A lot of issues have been recently fixed in `ruby-core` that could affect the `next` command in `byebug` so hopefully this won't happen again in `ruby 2.2` nor in the next patch level release of `ruby 2.1`. Have a look at the current state of this issue [here](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/16#issuecomment-47673108).