# Automatically step through with Byebug based on rule

Tags: ruby, byebug

I'm using Byebug to debug my rails application. Currently I'm using `step` to trace the program as it executes. I'm **not** interested in tracing execution through every single line of third-party libraries, I only want to step through **my** code application.

An example(using rails, but it wouldn't have to be rails):

I put a `byebug` into one of my controllers and then step through have the following files:

1. `/.../app/controllers/home_controller.rb`
2. `/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails_4_2_2/gems/devise-3.5.5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`
3. `/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails_4_2_2/gems/devise-3.5.5/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`
4. `/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails_4_2_2/gems/warden-1.2.4/lib/warden/session_serializer.rb`
5. `/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails_4_2_2/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb`
6. `Many other files here...`
7. `/.../app/...some_other_file_in_my_app`

I would like to be able to skip steps `2-6` and go straight to the next line of **my** code. Basically just skip past all third-party libraries when I'm `step`ing through my code. Is there a way to automatically skip files meet certain specifications (such as having a `.rvm` in the file path)?

I found this question: [byebug, next into application code only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249037/byebug-next-into-application-code-only?rq=1)

But it assumes that you know the line number you're headed to. I'm using byebug to trace where the code is going(exploring a cloned project).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Byebug cheatsheet: http://fleeblewidget.co.uk/2014/05/byebug-cheatsheet/

You can experiment with execution control methods such as `next X` to skip `X` amount of lines. Or maybe `finish X` to skip `X` amount of frames.

With those execution control methods you will be able to achieve skipping large amounts of code when you step too deep into the framework. However, there is no way to set breakpoints that only step though *your* code. The computer has no way of telling your code apart from the framework and its dependencies.

Comment: I understand that the computer has no way of knowing what is my code and what is a third-party library... That's why I wondered if there was a way to do it based on the path of the file.

Comment: well, ^ there you go.